# How to update a value while inserting rows from one table into another?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert rows into a table while ignoring duplicate entries. At the same time, I want to assign a value to a certain column in the newly inserted rows.

Here's what I have so far (without assigning the value)

```
INSERT INTO stats (unique_key,clicks) 
SELECT unique_key,clickss FROM temp_stats 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stats.unique_key=temp_stats.unique_key;
```

I would like to throw in `clicks = 20` for the newly inserted rows.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You want to use `20` instead of the value from `clickss` ?

Comment: Not quite. I want to update the clicks to 20 on the inserted rows.

Comment: thats what i mean. currently in your insert, `clicks` is being set to the value `clickss` from the `temp_stats` table.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the literal value, instead of the field from the table.

```
INSERT INTO stats (unique_key,clicks) 
SELECT unique_key,20 FROM temp_stats 
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stats.unique_key=temp_stats.unique_key;
```